# my model does not perform python and tensorflow process, keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

```
import sys
import os
import tensorflow
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import  Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

K.clear_session()

datos_de_entrenamiento = './data/entrenamiento' #Carpeta de imagenes
datos_de_validacion    = './data/validacion'    #Carpeta de imagenes para hacer validacion

#Parametros iniciales

epocas                 = 20       # Numero de veces a reiterar en nuestro procesamiento
altura, longitud       = 150,150  # Tamaño en el que se van a procesar las imagenes, cambiando el tamaño con alt 100px y long=100px
batch_size             = 32       # Numero de imagenes que se manda a procesar en nuestro computador
pasos                  = 1000     # Numero de veces a procesar la información en cada epoca 
pasos_validacion       = 200      # Corre 200 pasos al final de cada validación de datos para ver que esta aprendiendo el algoritmo
filtroConv1            = 32       # Filtros a aplicar en cada convolucion
filtroConv2            = 64       # Filtros a aplicar en cada convolucion
tamano_filtro1         = (3,3)    # Tamaño de filto a usar en la convolucion
tamano_filtro2         = (2,2)    # Tamaño de filto a usar en la convolucion
tamano_pool            = (2,2)    # Tamaño de filto a usar en el maxpooling
clases                 = 2        # Numero de carpetas contenedoras de nuestras imagenes
lr                     = 0.0005   # El tamño de los ajustes que hace nuestra red neuronal para ir a una solución optima

#Preprocesamiento de imagenes

##Preparamos nuestras imagenes

entrenamiento_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

entrenamiento_generador = entrenamiento_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    datos_de_entrenamiento,
    target_size=(altura, longitud),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validacion_generador = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    datos_de_validacion,
    target_size=(altura, longitud),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
# Creacion de red convolucional 

cnn=Sequential()
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtroConv1, tamano_filtro1, padding='same', input_shape=(altura,longitud,3), activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtroConv2, tamano_filtro2, padding='same', activation='relu'))

cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(Dense(clases, activation='softmax'))
cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=lr), metrics=['accuracy'])

cnn.fit_generator(
    entrenamiento_generador,
    steps_per_epoch=pasos,
    epochs=epocas,
    validation_data=validacion_generador,
    validation_steps=pasos_validacion)

dir='./modelo/'

if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.mkdir(dir)
    
cnn.save('./modelo/modelo.h5')
cnn.save_weights('./modelo/pesos.h5')

Found 460 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 460 images belonging to 2 classes.
```

Epoch 1/20
15/1000 [..............................] - ETA: 2:18:49 - loss: 1.5865 - accuracy: 0.5543WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 20000 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

It does not pass 15 and the process is finished.

Comment: There is no need to set steps per epoch and validation steps if you are using ImageDataGenerator, that is probably the problem, you set those parameters to the wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

Your steps per epoch is too large for your current dataset size, try lowering it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your `steps_per_epoch` is larger than your data size.

your `steps_per_epoch` should not be greater than  `total_images//batch_size`
if your total_data_size = 460, steps_per_epoch would be `460//32` ==14.

```
steps_per_epoch * batch_size = number_of_rows_in_train_data
```

So change the `steps_per_epoch` in `fit_generator`:

```
    cnn.fit_generator(
    entrenamiento_generador,
    steps_per_epoch=14,
    epochs=epocas,
    validation_data=validacion_generador,
    validation_steps=pasos_validacion)
```

Comment: Epoch 1/20
 1/14 [=>............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6338 - accuracy: 0.6429WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 280 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset. the problem insists